How to install soft start module on table saw?
I"m installing a soft start module on my Craftsman 10" model 315.34972. This saw starts SUPER hard, so I bought a soft start module from Amazon: Hitachi 371468 Soft Start Module.
Here is the original wiring setup:

I have two other options:
Options 1:

the first one works. It powers on, and start-up isn't nearly as jarring, but the spin-up doesn't take as long as I'd expected. It is still a huge improvement though.
The module itself has an adjustment to increase or decrease the spin-up of the motor. That doesn't seem to do anything. This leads me to believe it's not wired properly. The second issue is that this setup leaves a terminal on the switch with nothing connected. I'm concerned about the electrical or fire hazard.
Option 2:

This option also results in the saw powering up, and no open terminal. However, it doesn't seem like the soft start is as soft as option 1.
I'm using male/female spade connectors, and proper wires, but don't feel like I'm getting the performance I expected based on videos I've seen of this module on other tools. Is there another way to wire this?

Neither of those looks right. You're bypassing the switch in the first one, and the soft-start in the second one.


The connections on the saw this is designed for are slightly different, but basically the idea is the motor black lead (only) goes to module black, while switched hot (your switch terminal 1) goes to module brown, and switched neutral (your switch terminal 2) goes to module blue and motor white.
You don't have the separate set of stator/brake black wires the Hitachi motor does. Apparently this lead you to making some black-to-black connections in "option 2" that have the effect of bypassing the soft-start circuit by connecting the motor without going through it.

OK, that makes way more sense. So I didn't need to do anything with the power coming in. The only thing I had to go on was the reviews on Amazon, and videos on youtube which are largely unhelpful on this subject.
